# How to support multiple samplers for multiple reporters?

Tags: zipkin, opentracing, brave

When using Tracing.newBuilder() to create tracing, I found I can only specify 1 sampler and 1 reporter.

I'm trying to have:

- 100% sample for reporter A
- 1% sample for reporter B

Is it doable?

Thanks

Leon

Answer (score 0):

In Brave4,only one Tracing instance exist,so it can't be done.